# Using a double expression

Tags: word-usage

I want to say that the students sketched vertical asymptote instead of horizontal asymptote. Should I double "asymptote" or:

> sketched vertical asymptote instead of horizontal

Comment: Either is acceptable grammatically. I don't know enough about drawing to know what terminology is acceptable within that sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both variations are acceptable, it's simply a matter of style and preference.

There are other variations that could be used:

> The students sketched vertical rather than horizontal asymptotes.

This variation sounds more natural to me than the second one you suggested (which, while technically correct, is unusual).

But long as the meaning is clear, you can use an elliptical construction and leave out the repetition of certain words—not only at the end of a sentence but at its start.

---

Note that there is a slight issue with the grammar of your own sentences.  Corrected versions include:

> The students sketched vertical asymptote**s** instead of horizontal asymptote**s**.
>   The students sketched **a** vertical asymptote instead of **a** horizontal asymptote.
>   The students sketched vertical asymptote**s** instead of horizontal.
>   The students sketched **a** vertical asymptote instead of **a** horizontal.